# GraphServiceClient - how to define the request body?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

**Background**

I have an azure function app that in part, includes the following logic:

```
       var ApplicationClientID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID");
        var ApplicationClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_CLIENT_SECRET");
        var AzureTenantID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_TENANT");

        string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        
        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        // using https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential 
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            AzureTenantID, ApplicationClientID, ApplicationClientSecret, options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        
        var result = await graphClient.Users["<myguid>"].GetAsync();
        return result;
```

Now I want to replace the last 2 lines with a call to Microsoft Search api.  I've tested first via ms graph explorer like so:

[image]

It gives me the results I'm looking for.  So I copied the c# code snippet from Graph Explorer into my project.

The code now looks like this:

```
       var ApplicationClientID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID");
        var ApplicationClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_CLIENT_SECRET");
        var AzureTenantID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZ_TENANT");

        string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        
        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        // using https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential 
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            AzureTenantID, ApplicationClientID, ApplicationClientSecret, options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

       //****** THIS IS WHERE THE MS SEARCH API LOGIC STARTS ********//
       var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody
      {
         Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
        {
            new SearchRequest
                {
                EntityTypes = new List<EntityType?>
                {
                    EntityType.DriveItem,
                },
                Query = new SearchQuery
                {
                    QueryString = "some search criteria",
                },
                From = 0,
                Size = 35,
                QueryAlterationOptions = new SearchAlterationOptions
                {
                    EnableSuggestion = true,
                    EnableModification = true,
                },
            },
        },
     };
var result = await graphClient.Search.Query.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

But I'm getting some compile errors.

**Versions**

[image]

**library references**

[image]

**Problems**

The error I'm coming across is "The type or namespace name 'Beta' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

on this line:

```
 var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody
```

I added a baseUrl to the graphClient so it points to beta and then change the requestBody assignment.

```
 var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/");
```

But it's not clear how I should change the call to Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody because I don't have that method in the GraphServiceClient I have created.

So I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

The note in Graph Explorer indicates that the code snippets are all based on 5.x which I have.
Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, when we use beta version graph API, we need url like `/beta/xxx` instead of `/v1.0/xxx`. And if we want to use beta version query via Graph SDK, we also need to use beta version. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jieVQ.png

Comment: by the way, if we installed beta version Microsoft.Graph, it might also require to use beta version of Azure.Identity.. not very sure about this point because I didn't test it recently. In the new version SDK, it might not demand it. Just a tip...

Comment: If you can use v1.0 then use `new Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody` instead of `new Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody`, otherwise you need to use nuget `Microsoft.Graph.Beta`

Comment: Please see update 1.  I am no longer using beta.

Comment: You have to look into the `ex.Error.InnerError` to get the concrete error message back.

Comment: these are two completely separate issues, one is namespace, and another one is request exception. please close this one and post a new question including exception details

Comment: @YehorAndrosov kk makes sense.  Will close and post new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the suggested comments above, I changed the logic to not use beta:

```
  var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
                                    
  var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query.QueryPostRequestBody
```